# Implementing Task<T> for a remote call than responds in an event?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have an API whose interface looks like this:

```
void SendRequest(Guid id, IRequest request);
event EventHandler<ResponseEventArgs> ResponseReceived;
```

What's the best way of implementing this method?

```
Task<T> GetResponse(IRequest request) where T: IRequest
```

Note that multiple requests may overlap each other, so when a response comes back I need to look up the parent request.  I have a feeling TaskCompletionSource may be of use, but can't quite piece it together.

Comment: How does `ResponseEventArgs` look like? What is the purpose of having the type parameter `T` in the `Task` version, when it doesn't seem to be used in the event version?

Comment: @svick ResponseEventArgs has the id and an IResponse. A given type of request as a given response type (T), so I just want to cast to it to make the API a bit nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**:

If you want to do this without blocking a thread, you can do something like this using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

var requestIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();

EventHandler<ResponseEventArgs> handler = null;

handler = (sender, args) =>
{
    if(args.RequestIdentifier == requestIdentifier)
    {
        api.ResponseReceived -= handler; 

        // TrySetResult avoids re-entrancy problems in case of an
        // API that sends duplicates, but there other ways of 
        // dealing with this too.
        completionSource.TrySetResult((T)args.Response);
    }      
};


api.ResponseReceived += handler; 

// Make this async if you want.
api.SendRequest(requestIdentifier, request); 

return completionSource.Task;
```

---

**Original Answer:**

I think you want something like the following, which uses a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to block the thread until the event is raised by the API:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew<T>(() =>
{
    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    T result = default(T);

    var requestIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();

    EventHandler<ResponseEventArgs> handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
         if(args.RequestIdentifier == requestIdentifier)
         {
             result = (T)args.Response; // Not sure how this looks in your API
             waitHandle.Set(); // Unblock the thread running the task     
         }      
    };

    // Attach handler to respond to the response being received.
    api.ResponseReceived += handler; 

    // Send request off.
    api.SendRequest(requestIdentifier, request); 

    // Wait until response is received.
    waitHandle.WaitOne(); 

    // Detach handler to prevent leak.
    api.ResponseReceived -= handler; 

    return result;
});
```

---

For a cleaner way of doing this, look into [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Seems a bit expensive to block a thread?  What about overlapping requests and responses?  I need to associate them presumably.

Comment: @James L: I've put in an update to address the overlapping requests case. If you don't want to block a thread, just use the event provided in the API!

Comment: Thanks Ani for the solution.  I'm convinced a solution is out there which would allow me to await the result without hogging a ThreadPool thread.  If nothing is forthcoming I'll accept yours :)

Comment: Good stuff Ani!  I'd got as far as that myself.  Sadly you can't reference handler to unsubscibe until it is declared, i.e. outside of the handler.  I'd like to avoid maintaining a dictionary of ids -> task completion sources, because then I have synchronization to worry about.

Comment: @JamesL: What do you mean? By assigning the variable to `null` first (as I have done), you can get around that. Note that it is captured so there is no problem here at all. I don't see how a dictionary of ids -> task completion sources helps you at all, really. The API doesn't let you register a fine-grained response handler per request.

Comment: Ah of course, it works.  Can't believe I missed that.  Its been a long day. Thanks man, I certainly made you work for this one :)  I think we've arrived at a really good solution.

Comment: @JamesL, if you wanted to go with a dictionary, you could use `ConcurrentDictionary`, so that you wouldn't have to worry about synchronization.

Comment: @James L: If you're concerned about re-entrancy into that `if` block because of a weird API, consider using `completionSource.TrySetResult`.

Comment: @svick, Good idea but ConcurrentDictionary does actually use locking, just a lot less chance of a deadlock due to large number of buckets.  Best avoided altogether if possible.

Comment: @Ani, thanks.  I think actually in this case it is safe, but good thought!

Comment: @Ani I think your second answer is a lot better then the first, might be worth switching them around of even losing the first?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a task that waits for the event to return:

```
Task<T> GetResponse<T>() 
{
    T result = default(T);
    ManualResetEvent ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ResponseReceived += (s,e) =>  {     
        result = default(T); /* result = e.Xxx */
        ev.Set();
    };
    return new Task<T>(() => {
        SendRequest(Guid.NewGuid());        
        ev.WaitOne();
        return result;
    });
}
```